# sipcmd doesn't detect remote connection state change

Tags: sip, opalvoip

I try to use [sipcmd](https://github.com/tmakkonen/sipcmd) to call a phone number and play a wav file.

I use the command that way ( playing DTMF just for test):

```
./sipcmd -P sip -u 0033972nnnnnn -c passwd -w sip3.ovh.fr -x "w5000;c0033661nnnnnn;d123;ws500;h"
```

After few seconds, my phone rings. I answer but sipcmd continues its timeout count up and finally hangs up with the error `Call: Dial timed out`. 
Same thing if I terminates the call before the end of the timeout.

Looking a the code in debug, `WaitForStateChange()` desesperately stays in `CONNECTING` state whatever happens on the remote called.

Any idea on the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The timeout indicates that the server sip3.ovh.fr didn't reply, the best option would be to verify that the call can be made with a softphone before to discard any connectivity issues.

Comment: yes I check it and it works with a softphone even with CSipSimple which is based on opal AFAIK and using the same voip account.

Comment: might it be related to the sessions on your firewall maybe, I've experienced similar stuff.

Comment: might be... I'll try outside from my local network ASAP. Thanks @user322049

Comment: Did it fix the issue?